# How to add more stuff in the Toolbar

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Currently we are limited to these 
Styles, Bold, Italic, Link, Unlink, Anchor, Table, BulletedList, Blockquote, Strike, Subscript,  Superscript

Is there any way to add more stuff over here  eg :color and  abc 
so that we can change abc properties according to our requirements in the css

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. See the official HOWTO: [configuring CKEditor in Apostrophe.](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/ckeditor.html) This also includes how to configure Apostrophe's HTML sanitization filter to allow the things you want.

Answer (score 0):

allowedTags: [ 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'blockquote', 'p', 'a', 'ul', 'ol','span',
            'nl', 'li', 'b', 'i', 'strong', 'em', 'strike', 'code', 'hr', 'br', 'div',
            'table', 'thead', 'caption', 'tbody', 'tr', 'th', 'td', 'pre','bgcolor',
            'sup', 'sub' ],

['Bold','span','h6','Italic','-','Subscript', 'Superscript', '-','Link'],*

So in allowedTag span is available but when i put same thing in the toolbar then i only see Bold , Italic but not span

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to add justify plugin to be able to align text right, left or center. But after following the instruccions in the documentation, I wonder if the plugin should be located in a specific folder (mine is at public/modules/apostrophe-areas/js/ckeditorPlugins/justify/) also how the plugin should be called at the Toolbar.

This is my code just in case: (located at lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/public/js/user.js)

```
apos.define('apostrophe-areas', {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    // Use the super pattern - don't forget to call the original method
    var superEnableCkeditor = self.enableCkeditor;
    self.enableCkeditor = function() {
      superEnableCkeditor();
      // Now do as we please
      CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('justify', '/modules/apostrophe-areas/js/ckeditorPlugins/justify/', 'plugin.js');
    };
  }
});
```